# Instance variables and attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

When I define `@foo=3` in the `initialize` method, I expect to access my variable like this.

```
class Object
  def initialize(v)
    @foo = v
  end

  Object.new.foo
```

That doesn't happen though. I need to write `attr_accessor :foo`. Why do I need to do this even though `@` already does that for me?

Comment: I think you may be missing an `end` in your code.

Answer (score 5):

One instance variable in Ruby is not public by default. And access should be granted based on accessors.

For read only `attr_reader`
For write only `attr_writer`
For read write `attr_accessor`

It is not accessible by default

Answer (score 4):

@ does not automatically do that for you. That's why. `attr_accessor` creates getters and setters for your instance variables ("@-variables").

Answer (score 3):

The instance variables are private. You need accessors and mutators to access them. A common accessor/mutator pair looks like:

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(value)
  @foo=value
end
```

This creates an abstraction which you can now use as:

```
Classname.new.foo
Classname.new.foo="OOP"
```

Since this is such a common need and also reults in lot of boilerplate(read: unnecessary) code, ruby provides a dynamic method which literally defines these two methods for you.

```
attr_accessor :foo
```

If you want only one of accessor or mutator method, then use the corresponding from following:

```
attr_reader :foo
attr_writer :foo
```

This will save a lot of copy/paste. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

*All* Ruby attributes are "private" and are invisible outside the class's methods. You need accessor methods to read and write an attribute. So, in your example, you need

```
class MyClass

  def initialize(v)
    @foo = v
  end

  def foo
    @foo
  end

  def foo=(v)
    @foo = v
  end

end
```

Then `MyClass.new(4).foo` will work, and return `4`.

You can also add the accessor methods using the convenience methods

```
attr_reader   :foo
attr_writer   :foo
```

or

```
attr_accessor :foo
```

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable starts with an @ character.  All instance variables are private, which means you can't read them and you can't change their value.  So what to do?

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name    #getter
    @name
  end

  def name=(str)  #setter
    @name = str
  end
end
```

Well, that gets to be a pain to type out, so ruby provides a shortcut:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```